# Cognos report Studio sum one row by year

Tags: cognos-10

I am working on a Cognos Report Studio Version 10

```
                       Year 1        Year 2        Year 3
        Item 1         100           200           300
        Item 2         600           600           600
```

Item 2 (each year) = Item 1(Year 1 + Year 2 + Year 3)

How can I do this report in Cognos Report Studio?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a data item to calculate the sum of years where item equals 1.

Data Item name: [Item 1 Total]

```
maximum(
CASE 
WHEN [Item] = 1 THEN [Year 1] + [Year 2] + [Year 3] 
ELSE 0 
END 
for report)
```

Set the data item's 'Aggregate Function' property to 'Calculated' to tell Cognos that you have supplied your own summary expression.

Now you need to modify the expression for the [Year 1],[Year 2], and [Year 3] data items to use the newly calculated sum.

```
CASE 
WHEN [Item] = 2 THEN [Item 1 Total] 
ELSE [Year 1] 
END
```

Use the same expression for Year 2 and Year 3 and just change the data item referenced in the ELSE clause.